# Required to do some string operation in Transferred value from property transfer in SoapUI?

Tags: soapui, web-api-testing

Requirement is to get substring from transferred value from property transfer:
eg. from source, response gave abcdefg value to be transfer and I want efg in request of target, then where I have to do modification to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XPath substring function in the source part of the Property Transfer step. For example, in the following the starting value of `TestValue` is `abcdefg`:

[image]

This takes the original value of the `TestValue` element, substrings from the fifth element to the end of the string, and transfers that value to another property.